# Getting the gcd of a list

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell, actually I just started, and I would like to get a small hint to the question I am about to ask.

I am currently trying to get the GCD of a given list. For example, having the list [3, 6, 9] it will return 3.

For the moment, I tought of the following aproach, am I going in a good direction?

```
let getGCD l = map (\x y -> gcd x y) l
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite, you don't want `map` but rather a fold. `map` will let you transform every element in the list uniformly, so you give it a local transformation `a -> b` and it gives you a global transformation (`[a] -> [b]`). This isn't really what you want.

As a quick primer on folds, there's a whole family of them which all let us express computations which we build up by repeatedly applying a function to an initial value, the next element and the list, and then repeating with the result of that application as the new initial value. So `foldl' (+) 0 [1, 2, 3, 4]` would so something like

```
 foldl' (+) 0 [1, 2, 3, 4] ==>
 foldl' (+) 1 [2, 3, 4] ==>
 foldl' (+) 3 [3, 4] ==>
 foldl' (+) 6 [4] ==>
 foldl' (+) 10 [] ==> -- For empty lists we just return the seed given
 10
```

Can you see how to slot your problem into this framework?

### More hints

You want to take a list and compute a result which depends on every element of the list, something like

```
gcdAll :: [Int] -> Int
gcdAll l = foldl' step initial l
```

is closer to what you want where `step` takes the current gcd of the list you've processed so far and the next element of the list and returns the next value and initial is the value to start with (and what is returned if `l` is empty. Since there isn't really a sane value, I'd instead split this into

```
gcdAll :: [Int] -> Maybe Int
gcdAll [] = Nothing
gcdAll (h : rest) = Just $ foldl' step h rest
```

so that you correctly signal the possibility of failure, after all, what's the gcd of nothing?

Note that `foldl'` is imported from `Data.List`.

Comment: I would do something like foldl gcd 1 [3, 6, 9] , but it is still not working. Actually, I just defined `gcdAll :: [Integer] -> Integer
gcdAll l = foldl gcd 1 l` And it always returns 1.

Comment: @TimothyWalker You're very close but there's a problem with your choice of initial value, what's the GCD of 1 and anything else?

Comment: Oh, thank you, I figured it out, I have to do `gcdAll l = foldl gcd (first value of l) (list "remaining")` , I am going to use head to get the first item from the list and tail to get the rest, omg. thank you xD

Comment: @TimothyWalker Im glad you got it! Be sure you check out the stuff with Maybe in my answer because you don't want your code to blow up if you give it an empty list

Answer (score 1):

You can recursively use gcd on a list (essentially a fold implementation)

```
gcd' :: (Integral a) => [a] -> a
gcd' [] = 1
gcd' [x] = x
gcd' (x:xs) = gcd x (gcd' xs)
```

Comment: `lcm' [] = 1`, but I don't think `gcd' []` is sensible.

Answer (score 0):

A GCD is a property of a pair of numbers. So, really, you want to look at *pairs* of numbers drawn from your list. Ultimately you want to end up with a single GCD for the entire list, but as a first step, you want pairs.

There's a widely-known trick for working with consecutive pairs:

```
f1 list = zipWith f2 list (tail list)
```

The `zipWith` function is a bit like `map`, but works with a *pair* of lists. In this case, the original list, and the tail of the original list. (Note that this fails if the list is empty.) If you replace `f2` with your `gcd` function, you now have a new list which is the GCD of each consecutive pair of numbers. And this list is one element shorter than the original:

```
f1 [x, y, z, w] ==> [gcd x y, gcd y z, gcd z w]
```

So each time you apply `f1` to a list, you get a new, shorter list of GCDs. Apply it enough times, and you should end up with just one element...

Comment: this approach will make it unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I just tackled this one and this would be the quickest, simplest

```
myGCDMultiple = foldr1 gcd

> myGCDMultiple [3,6,9]
3
```